# Multithreading or asyncio with AWS IoT Device SDK v2 for Python

Tags: aws-iot

I'm developing an application on a Linux embedded system that is a sort of gateway between a serial (RS485) bus and AWS IoT Core. I'm using AWS IoT Device SDK v2 for Python.

The application is a typical home building automation. Suppose a lamp and a temperature sensor connected serially to the Linux box. They talks a custom protocol. On the other side there's AWS IoT.

The use cases are:

- A MQTT message from AWS can power on/off the lamp (remote command that changes device status)
- A MQTT message from AWS requests the current status of lamp and the temperature level
- When the temperature reaches an over or under threshold, a MQTT message must be sent to AWS IoT Core.

I can't decide what is a good architecture of this application. I'm thinking about multithreading (that I know) and asyncio (that I don't know).

**Multithreading**

I can start one thread for serial protocol (pyserial) and another thread for MQTT connection (awscrt, awsiot). Both waits for something (incoming bytes over serial bus or incoming messages over MQTT connection). So both of them blocks on I/O.

I'm not sure how to use shared data structures. Indeed, the lamp status (that could be complex: on/off, dimmer value, rgb color, errors, and so on) can be accessed by the serial bus thread (a new status is received from the lamp device) and by IoT thread (a status request can be received from AWS).
Should I use Locks everytime the data structure is accessed by one or the other thread?

**asyncio**

awscrt libraries seem written around asyncio, because they use Futures and callbacks. So I can define two asyncio.Task: one for serial (serial_asyncio) and one for MQTT connection. In this cooperative scenario, race conditions shouldn't happen. However it's very difficult for me to use asyncio and it seems to me there isn't a single asyncio example with AWS IoT Device SDK v2 for Python.

Any help?

Comment: I'd suggest to use greengrass v2 in your case. With Greengrass v2, you write small applications called components. In your case, you would have 1 component that would use Greengrass IPC to listen to specific topic (you Bridge component to make transfer to/from AWS IoT Core).

Comment: I don't know Greengrass and sincerely I don't want to learn it now. At the moment I need only to receive and send messages over a simple MQTT connection.